# Help interpret Distribution of Wlan Signal Strength Measurements

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

For my project I need to evaluate large amounts of wlan signal strength measurements.

Measurement is in [dBm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm) which is a logarithmic scale for milli watt (so every 3dBm the milliwatts double) where 0dBm is 1 milliwatt and -100 dBm is 0.1 pW. Received Wlan Signal Strengths are usally from -30dBm (very good) to -95 dBm (very bad).

These 2 examples were one Router measureing another's received signal strength:

- First is the measurment over time; the red line is a naiive linear regression line. The blue and yellow plot bands are the 60% and 80% confidence intervalls; green dotted line is mean
- The second graph shows the frequency distribtuion and the red line is the [CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) of a normal distribution with given mean and std dev

**Distribution 1:** (Samplesize: 500, Mean: -49.51, Median: -49, Mode: -49, σ: 1.77)
[image: Brainwavez Signal Strength over Time]
[image: Brainwavez Frequency Distribution]

**Distribution 2** (Samplesize: 500, Mean: -64.41, Median: -64, Mode: -64, σ: 3.02)
[image: NodeSignal Strength over Time]
[image: NodeFrequency Distribution]

Practically everytime I get mean = median = mode (with +/-1) but a nice distribution curve that fits a normal distribution CDF only with high measurements.

My question is how would you classify this distribution? I heard log-normal but a CDF did not fit any of my distributions.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that it's not one distribution but a mixture of distributions, where each one relates to a specific state of the system (don't know enough about routers) or maybe there are events happening (like RF interference) at some times which increase/lower the signal strength. If you can relate the large changes, especially in the 2nd plot after 19:00, to some other information like what the router is actually doing, you might get more insight.

Comment: ill give you the bounty since there were no other answers in time